# TYPO3 extension: Prevent record to be saved if the user enters the wrong value

Tags: typo3

I want to implement an eval in TYPO3 for a specific field in a TCA that prevents the record to be saved in the backend if the BE user enters a restricted value (like if doesn't enter anything or the input contains specific characters). So far i can only change the value in the eval function if it's not allowed, but i want the record NOT to be saved if the BE user clicks on 'save' while the field has restricted value. Is this even possible via an eval?

Edit: A cheap way to do this would be setting $value to NULL in the eval function if the input is of a restricted value, but that's definitely not the elegant way to do things as it throws an SQL error that might confuse the BE user.

So i basically need a way to prevent TYPO3 to persist the repository... Or to set the record back to the state it was in before the BE user clicked on 'save'...

Edit2: This is what i have... Nothing to exciting, just an IPv4 evaluation. But again, it changes only the value to something else, it DOESN'T prevent the creation or editing of the record if the input was not an IPv4.

```
<?php

namespace Cjk\Icingaconfgen\Evaluation;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\FlashMessage;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\FlashMessageService;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;

/**
 * Class for field value validation/evaluation to be used in 'eval' of TCA
 */
class IPv4Evaluation
{

    /**
     * @param string $value 
     * @param string $is_in
     * @param bool $set
     * @return string
     */
    public function evaluateFieldValue($value, $is_in, &$set)
    {
        if (!filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
            $value = 'Fehlerhafte Eingabe (IPv4)';

            /** @var FlashMessage $message */
            $message = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Messaging\\FlashMessage',
            'Fehlerhafte Eingabe: .conf Datei wird nicht erstellt/editiert. Neue services können nicht hinzugefügt oder editiert werden.',
            \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\FlashMessage::ERROR, 
            TRUE 
            );

            /** @var $flashMessageService FlashMessageService */
            $flashMessageService = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(FlashMessageService::class);
            $flashMessageService->getMessageQueueByIdentifier()->enqueue($message);
            }
            return $value;
    }
}
```

So basically, and correct me if i'm wrong, the eval happens BETWEEN the input of the BE user (right after he clicks on the save button) and the persisting of the record. So there has to be a way to prevent the persisting of the new data, not only to change it at will.

I hope this makes my question more clear now, i don't know what else to write to explain it.

Comment: Show us what you tried. I think eval must be the way to go.

Comment: I've edited my question and added the eval code i have. But really, it's nothing special, just an IPv4 eval.

Answer (score 0):

I show you a example of a validation in TCA. If validation failed record can't saved.

File myextension/Classes/Validation/Validator/MinReferencesValidator.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Myextension\Validation\Validator;

/**
 * Validator for min references
 */
class MinReferencesValidator extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Validation\Validator\AbstractValidator {

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $supportedOptions = [
            'min' => [0, 'The minimum references to accept', 'integer'],
    ];

    /**
     * The given value is valid if it contains more then min items
     *
     * @param mixed $value The value that should be validated
     * @return void
     */
    public function isValid($value) {

        if (!is_object($value)) {
            $this->addError(
                    $this->translateErrorMessage(
                            'LLL:EXT:myextension/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:validator_object_notvalid',
                            'myextension'
                    ), 1489870657);
            return;
        }

        $minimum = $this->options['min'];
        $countItems = count($value);

        if ($countItems < $minimum) {
            $this->addError(
                    $this->translateErrorMessage(
                            'LLL:EXT: myextension/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:validator_min_references',
                            'myextension',
                            [
                                $minimum
                            ]
            ), 1489872300, [$minimum]);
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

File myextension/Classes/Domain/Model/Youritem.php

```
/**
 * Image of supplier (image reference)
 *
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference>
 * @validate NotEmpty, \Vendor\Yourextension\Validation\Validator\MinReferencesValidator(min=1)
 */
protected $images;
```